# Inserting AJAX loading indicator into a statement with multiple AJAX calls

Tags: jquery

What is the best way of inserting an AJAX loading indicator into a statement with multiple AJAX calls?

For example:

```
$("#search_building").on("change blur", function () {
    var building = $("#search_building").val();
    var room = $("#search_room").val();
    var dept = $("#dept").val();
    var dataString = 'room=' + room + '&' + 'building=' + building + '&' + 'dept=' + dept;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_building.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#search_room').html(html);
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableMon.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#grid2_mon').html(html);
        }
    });
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableTue.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#grid2_tue').html(html);
        }
    });
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableWed.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#grid2_wed').html(html);
        }
    });
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_timetableFri.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#grid2_wed').html(html);
        }
    });
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process_roomList.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
            $('#list2').html(html);
        }
    });
        });
```

Comment: You want the ajax request starts only after previous one completed?

Comment: @Teddy no - sorry about the misunderstanding. I want the loading icon to appear in the success target div/select/etc

Comment: @coder 's ajaxSetup will be a good solution. But in this case better to include a counter, else indicator will hide when any one of the requests completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it Something like this in your `$.ajax()` call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function(){
        // show image here
        $("#busy").show();
    },
    complete:function(){
        // hide image here
        $("#busy").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How would I incorporate this into the above code? I'd love to see an example :-)

Comment: Here is an example for what you're looking for http://skfox.com/jqExamples/AjaxActivity.html

Answer (score 2):

From my [blog](http://thebigredgeek.blogspot.com/2013/02/ajax-indicators.html):

Using counters and other substandard approaches will encourage code dysfunction down the road as your code base becomes harder and harder to read and maintain.  The IDEAL way to accomplish this is by using an event-driven approach.  It is easier to maintain and leads to less spaghetti code down the road.  You can easily implement something like this:

```
//First, we need an object that will contain our 'event domain'
var EventDomain = new function(config,callback){

this.__listeners = {}; //this will store references to functions associated to events

this.on = function(event,listener){ //here, we provide a member that binds 
                                    //a 'listener' function to an event string
    if (typeof this.__listeners[event] == "undefined"){
        this.__listeners[event] = [];
    }
    this.__listeners[event].push(listener);
};
this.emit = function(event,params){ //here, we provide a member that 'emits' an
                                    //event string, calling any 'listener' functions
                                    //and passing a parameter object 
                                    //{param1: val1, param2:val2, paramN, valN} 
    if(typeof event == "string"){
        event = { type: event };
    }
    if(!event.target){
        event.target = this;
    }

    if(!event.type){
        throw new Error("Event object missing 'type' property.");
    }
    if(this.__listeners[event.type] instanceof Array){
        var listeners = this.__listeners[event.type];
        for (var i=0, len=listeners.length; i < len; i++){
            listeners[i](params);
        }
    }
};
this.removeListener = function(type, listener){ //here, we provide a member that allows
                                                //us to remove a 'listener' function 
                                                //from an event
    if(this.__listeners[type] instanceof Array){
        var listeners = this.__listeners[type];
        for (var i=0, len=listeners.length; i < len; i++){
            if (listeners[i] === listener){
                listeners.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
this.removeAllListeners = function(type){ //here, we provide a member that allows
                                          //us to remove ALL 'listener' functions
                                          //from an event
    if(this.__listeners[type] instanceof Array){
        delete this.__listeners[type];
    }
};
};
```

Now that we have an event domain, we can use it with your above code snippet.  But first, lets create an object to act as a controller for our ajax calls:

```
var AjaxController = new function(){  
    var counter;  //create a private member called counter
    this.onLoad = function(fn){ //here, we provide a member to specify what to do
                                //when ajax requests begin
        EventEmitter.on('ajax_loading',(function(fn){ //bind 'ajax_loading' event to an  
                                                      //ajax loading indicator
            return function(){ //yet another closure
                if(counter<1){ //obviously, we only want to do something on the first
                               //load, not every single time.  Otherwise, you'll end
                               //end up trying to show the exact same loading animation
                               //for each ajax call
                    fn();
                }
                counter++;
            };
        })(fn));
    };

    this.onComplete = function(fn){ //here we provide a member to specify what to do
                                    //when ALL ajax requests have finished
        EventEmitter.on('ajax_complete',(function(fn){ //bind the 'ajax_complete' event 
                                                       //to a loading indicator
            return function(){ //yet another closure
                counter--; //decrement concurrent loading
                if(counter<1){ //its only finished once the counter is 0!
                   fn();
                }
            }
        })(fn));
    };

    var constructor = function(){ //good object oriented programming uses constructors!
        counter = 0;
        //Now, lets overload the original $.ajax method to provide functionality
        //for our event driven approach
        $.ajax = (function(ajax){ //this is called a 'closure'.  
                                  //We pass it the original function and it wraps and 
                                  //returns it, overloading the original method                                       
            function overloadAjax(params){ //this is our overloading function
                  if(params.success){ //if there is a success parameter passed
                                      //to the ajax call, overload that as well
                                      //to emit the 'ajax_complete' event
                     params.success = (function(success){
                         function overloadSuccess(data){
                             EventDomain.emit('ajax_complete');
                             success(data);
                         }
                         return overloadSuccess; //return and overload success
                     })(params.success);
                  }
                  EventDomain.emit('ajax_loading'); //emit the 'ajax_loading' event
                                                    //for each ajax call
                  ajax(params);
            }
            return overloadAjax; //here we return 'overload' back to $.ajax, overloading       
                                 //the original
        })($.ajax);


    }
    constructor(); //we call the constructor after all members have been prototyped 
}
```

Now that we have created a nice, reusable ajax loader toolkit for ourselves, lets put it to use:

```
AjaxController.onLoad(function(){
   //put some code here to do DOM manipulation to add a loader, or however you
   //want to 'indicate' ajax loading
});

AjaxController.onComplete(function(){
   //put some code here to do some DOM manipulation to remove your loader, or however
   //you want to 'indicate' that ajax loading is complete
});
```

Now, it JUST WORKS:

```
$("#search_building").on("change blur", function () {

var building = $("#search_building").val();
var room = $("#search_room").val();
var dept = $("#dept").val();
var dataString = 'room=' + room + '&' + 'building=' + building + '&' + 'dept=' + dept;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_building.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#search_room').html(html);
    }
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_timetableMon.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#grid2_mon').html(html);
    }
});
     $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_timetableTue.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#grid2_tue').html(html);
    }
});
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_timetableWed.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#grid2_wed').html(html);
    }
});
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_timetableFri.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#grid2_wed').html(html);
    }
});
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process_roomList.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#list2').html(html);
    }
});
    });
```

The great benefit to combining event driven programming with object oriented programming on
the front-end is that you end up freeing up your developers to do more actual content creation and less problem solving.  Creating a reusable framework takes more time to begin with, but has exponential time/quality benefits down the road.  If you would like more help
with these concepts, feel free to shoot me an email: rhyneandrew@gmail.com.
I'd be more than happy to help you out free of charge ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter to record the number of AJAX requests in progress. When the counter is > 1, show loading indicator. Everytime you get a response, decrement by 1. When the counter reaches 0, hide the loading indicator.